# What does “A media shut-in” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was drawn to the word, “a media shut-in” appearing in the following paragraph of New York Times’ (February 28) article that came under the headline, “Trump moves to become master of his own messages”:

> “The president reached his limit as **a media shut-in** after a
>   particularly tough week of headlines last month, when he decided he
>   wanted to fight back himself, despite the objections of some advisers,
>   at a hastily arranged news conference. The result was a 77-minute
>   Trump tour de force that was at least viewed as a cathartic exercise
>   for a frustrated commander in chief.”

I think I’m pretty familiar with “shut＋preposition” constructions such as “shut out,” “shut away, “shut down,” and “shut up,” but not with “shut in.”

Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary defines “shut sb in (sth)” as:
① to put sb in a room and keep them there. ② to go to room and stay there, 
but both definitions don’t seem to pertinently apply to the interpretation of “a media shut-in “ in the above quote.

What does “a media shut-in “ mean in the context of the above article? Mr. Trump cited many media including New York Times, Washington Post, CBC,  CNN as the enemy of American people. Then why is it "A media"?

Comment: A shut-in is somebody who is confined (or who confines himself) to staying indoors. This is often in response to a physical or mental disability that makes travel difficult. In this case, it's the restrictions of the Presidency that kept Trump limited in his response to the reporting. It's not *a media*; it's *a shut-in*. *Media* is an attributive noun describing what kind of isolation is involved.

Comment: It's a little unclear, but I'd guess that the intended meaning is that Trump had been a "shut-in" because he was avoiding the media.

Answer (score 1):

It means that he had decided not to shoot off at the mouth for awhile.  In other words, he had decided to take a break from putting his foot in his mouth, by just not making public statements.

It comes from *shut-in*.  A *shut-in* doesn't go out of the house, generally not by choice, but due to some health situation.

> A person confined indoors by illness or disability.
>   adj. (shŭt-ĭn′)
>
> 1. Confined to a home or hospital, as by illness.
> 2. Disposed to avoid social contact; excessively withdrawn or introverted.

But when he ended this period, he really let loose, according to the quote.  (I've been sticking my head in the sand and trying to pretend he didn't win.)

(http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shut-in)